# Implementing long complicated queries in Spring Boot + Postgresql that are dependent on data from backend processing

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to implement SCD type 2 + other data processing and aggregating into my PostgreSQL database so that I could do data analytics easily, fetch it and port that data onto a web app dashboard.

All the queries are written down in plain SQL that does all of the processing. I am required to drop, create and merge tables to achieve what I want so there are fairly complicated queries that are not fully adherent to any of the Spring entity models, thus, don't really fit in any repository.

I was thinking of creating a cron job on the server that would run the SQL queries, however, I need to run them after a cron job in Spring has finished processing and uploaded some data from external sources into the database so there might be clashes if I do it separately.

I was thinking of doing it boldly and just putting them as native queries in a 'related' repository and just running them sequentially.

Perhaps there is a better way how Spring boot and PostgreSQL could communicate and how could I run these queries? Is there any good way to run SQL commands through Spring Boot without using JPA repositories or entityManagers?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe move those queries to DB functions/procedures?

Comment: Now if there would only be something like a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). **Pro Tip** Spring Boot already has that configured for you.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, that looks like the thing I was looking for and missed it, sorry for such an obvious question.